# ploting afigure with large size in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot a figure with large size

Here is my code

```
% this code gives me good appearance
scrsz = get(0,'ScreenSize');
figure('Position',[30 50 scrsz(3)/1.2 scrsz(4)/1.2]);
```

my questions are:

is the appearance of the figure will change if this code run on a different computer?

is there a way to plot a figure with maximum screen size directly?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appearance of the figure definitely may change.

If you want a maximal screen size, I would use the following  [File Exchange submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10274-maximize-figure-windows).